# Making images "S" sized sometimes crops them - Is there an easy fix?

Tags: discussion, bug

I edited in some images to an old answer by bikeboy389 [Are there significant differences between different zesters?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/are-there-significant-differences-between-different-zesters/11151#11151). I ended up making them "m" sized although I first tried to make them "s". They are not earth-shattering images, and there are 3 of them. "S" was fine for the first one, cropped the second one in a way I could live with, and ruined the third one.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Is there an easy way deal with this?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on the "m" and "s" sizes? I thought imgur kept the uploaded size but when being displayed the maximum width is limited to about 630px but they seem a lot narrower. Doing the same thing I'd normally pick a reasonable size for the first one and then crop/resize on my PC so the others looked OK at the same image size.

Comment: @PeterJ in this case all of the images were of the item on Amazon. I just added "s" just before .jpg. Since that cropped the images poorly, I changed to "m.jpg" That's the only way I know how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Imgur API documentation](https://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs) the `s` suffix actually means "small square" not
"small thumbnail". This means the image is cropped to fit into a small square. You probably want
to use the `t` suffix which only resizes the image.

Here's the complete documentation on suffixes:

> There are 6 total thumbnails that an image can be resized to. Each one is accessable by
>   appending a single character suffix to the end of the image id, and before the file extension.
>   The thumbnails are:
>
> ```
> Thumbnail Suffix  Thumbnail Name   Thumbnail Size  Keeps Image Proportions 
> s                 Small Square     90x90           No 
> b                 Big Square       160x160         No 
> t                 Small Thumbnail  160x160         Yes 
> m                 Medium Thumbnail 320x320         Yes 
> l                 Large Thumbnail  640x640         Yes 
> h                 Huge Thumbnail   1024x1024       Yes
> ```
>
> For example, the image located at `http://i.imgur.com/12345.jpg` has
>   the Medium Thumbnail located at `http://i.imgur.com/12345m.jpg`

Here's what your second sample image looks like using the `s`, `t` and `m` suffixes:

[image: Small Square Example]
[image: Small Thumbnail Example]
[image: Medium Thumbnail Example]

If you want a different size than one of those listed above you can also use HTML directly in your post. For example if you wanted a really small thumbnail you could use this:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaKUB.jpg" height="20" />
```

To get this: 
 [image]

While this later method isn't as easy as just adding a suffix to the URL, it does have the advantage that people can view the full size image (as uploaded to Imgur) by right clicking on the thumbnail image.

Comment: See also this answer on Meta Stack Exchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74312/thumbnail-image-on-stack-overflow/138253#138253

Comment: Great to know, thanks!